# Read only selected columns in R read.csv

Tags: r, csv

I have encountered this strange xlsx file, which have a lot of empty columns, and when I swipe rightwards in Microsoft Excel, the empty columns kept appearing. I want to read this file using `read.csv`, but it gives me warning `In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls`, I am guessing this is because of the empty columns. How can I solve this and read it using `read.csv`? Thank you

Comment: Try `skip` argument!

Comment: I tried `mydata = read.csv("...xlsx", sep = ",", quote = "\"", skipNul = TRUE, skip=0)` but give me error `more columns than column names`

Comment: Set `skip=1` and `fill=T`

Comment: `mydata = read.csv("../data/wine_reviews_midterm_2021.xlsx",  sep = ",", quote = "\"", skipNul = TRUE, skip=1, fill=T)` will give me error `Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : invalid multibyte string 1`

Comment: Would you be able to copy the data into a new excel sheet and try again? I have had excel create empty columns and it messes up with R

Comment: This sounds like the data has some unintended column formatted (bytes, strings, etc.) As Daniel suggests I'd suggest reopening this file in a fresh excel sheet and try to save it again. You could also save it as `txt` or `fixed-width`. Make sure the data isn't formatted weirdly in excel (are there columns with a comma within a some of the file? Are there columns with empty names? stuff like this may affect your file when read in other programs).  You could also try using alternative packages `readr` (`read_csv`) or `data.table` (`fread`) and see if they work.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example of your data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what is the data structure and provide correct solution for your situation.